# Восстановление отсутствующих дней просрочки при помощи Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Всем привет! Уже писал сюда с этой проблемой на днях и получил пару дельных советов, получилось ее решить, но на реальном массиве данных работает очень медленно.

Датафрейм:

| Период | ДоговорЗайма | ДнейВПросрочке | debtm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 | 260 | 14036,83 |
| 02.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 | 0 | 14036,83 |
| 03.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 |  |  |
| 04.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 | 263 | 14036,83 |
| 01.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 321 | 18331 |
| 02.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 322 | 18331 |
| 03.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 323 | 18331 |
| 04.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 324 | 18331 |

Нужно получить:

| Период | ДоговорЗайма | ДнейВПросрочке | debtm | Просрочка |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 | 260 | 14036,83 | 260 |
| 02.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 | 0 | 14036,83 | 261 |
| 03.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 |  |  | 262 |
| 04.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE4F2883086F8 | 263 | 14036,83 | 263 |
| 01.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 321 | 18331 | 321 |
| 02.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 322 | 18331 | 322 |
| 03.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 323 | 18331 | 323 |
| 04.10.2022 | BFA6005056A5512711EBE506E2243B00 | 324 | 18331 | 324 |

Добился нужного результат с помощью такого кода:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dataset['Просрочка'] = 0
dataset.sort_values(by=['ДоговорЗайма', 'Период'], ascending=[True, False], inplace = True)
dataset = dataset.reset_index()
s = dataset['ДоговорЗайма'].unique()
dataset_copy = pd.DataFrame(index= [0,1],columns=dataset.columns)
dataset_copy=dataset_copy.drop(columns = 'index')
for k in range(len(s)):
    dataset_2 = dataset[dataset['ДоговорЗайма'] == s[k]]
    dataset_2 = dataset_2.reset_index()
    dataset_2 = dataset_2.drop(columns = 'index')
    i = 0
    while i< len(dataset_2):
        if dataset_2['ДнейВПросрочке'] [i] >0:
            for j in range(int(dataset_2['ДнейВПросрочке'][i])):
                dataset_2['Просрочка'] [j+i] = dataset_2['ДнейВПросрочке'][i]-j
            i=i+dataset_2['ДнейВПросрочке'][i]
        else :
            dataset_2['Просрочка'] [i] = 0
        i = i+1
    dataset_2 = dataset_2.drop(columns = 'level_0')
    dataset_copy = dataset_copy.append(dataset_2)
dataset_copy = dataset_copy.dropna (subset=['ДоговорЗайма'])
print(dataset_copy)
```

Но на реальном датасете (3млн строк) отрабатывает слишком долго и выдает при выполнении такие оповещения:
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
df_2['Просрочка'] [i] = 0
C:\Users\Daniil K\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4044\779933407.py:9: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Как можно улучшить код, чтобы он выполнялся какое-то адекватное время? Или возможно нужен другой подход?

Comment: Оповещения удалось выключить при помощи:
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

Но почему они появляются, кто-нибудь подскажет?

Comment: вам сама pandas говорит, почему. сходите по url и почитайте.  вкратце, вам говорят. что вы пытаетесь что-то сделать с копией (отображением) фрейма, а не с ним самим.